# Determine if improper integral converges or diverges (by comparison)

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

Attempt:
The integral diverges by comparison.  $1/log(x)$ $>$ $1/x$. $1/x$ from 0 to 1 to diverges.  Thus by comparison it diverges.

However, I'm not sure if my comparison is correct.  Is $log(x)<x$ for $0<x<1$?

Comment: Yes, $\log x<x$ for $0<x<1$, but, no, $1/\log x>1/x$ is false in that range.

Comment: So how would I show that the above integral is divergent?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^{0.5}{\frac{dx}{\log(x)}}$$
exists since $\frac{1}{\log(x)}$ is bounded on $]0,0.5]$

on $[0.5,1[$, $$\frac{1}{\log(x)}<\frac{4}{x-1}$$

Since $$\int_{0.5}^{1}{\frac{4dx}{x-1}}=-\infty$$
you have  $$\int_{0.5}^{1}{\frac{dx}{\log(x)}}=-\infty$$
and finally
$$\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{dx}{\log(x)}}=-\infty$$

Comment: Hi Im not familiar with what ]0,0.5] means and [0.5,1[.  What does this notation mean?and why does the integral exist because 1/log(x) is bounded for 0<x<0.5.  Doesn't the problem  occur at 0?

Comment: $]0,0.5] = \{x \in \mathbb{R}, 0 < x \leq 0.5\}$, $[0.5,1[ = \{x \in \mathbb{R}, 0.5  \leq x <1 \}$

Look at the graph of $\frac{1}{\log(x)}$, the problem occurs at $1$ because $\frac{1}{\log(x)} \to -\infty$ when $x\to 1$ with $x < 1$

Comment: I think one needs to include some justification of $1/\log x<4/(x-1)$for $.5\le x<1$.